# Folders uploading in Prepros

Tags: prepros

I'm making a new folder and place some files in it. When I'm trying to upload that new folder via FTP prepros shows an error (No such file or directory). As I understand it doesn't make that new folder and trying just to upload all file inside the folder. Why does this happen? (I'm using Prepros v6.0.5)

Comment: I've run into the same issue. Let me know if you found a solution.  Maybe permissions?

Answer (score 0):

While a little late, it's obvious this problem still exists
I was trying to upload from the "dist" folder, bur was getting told the file doesn't exist and noticed it was looking for a dist folder
When I changed the name of the dist folder to the same as the target folder everything went OK

I was aiming for /var/www/website/html
the files I was trying to upload were in ../../dist on my desktop
I change "dist" to "html" and deleted the html folder on the server
I then targeted...
/var/www/website
A new html folder with the files I was uploading was created inside the website folder
In brief:
Target the parent directory of the directory you want to create
Change the name of you local dist folder to the name of the directory you want to create on your server

- **local folder:** html/index.html
- **remote path:** /var/www/website
- **result:** /var/www/website/html/index.html

p.s.
Sorry for being long winded