# Prepros 6 SFTP directory uploaded to wrong path

Tags: upload, sftp, prepros

I have a directory upload issue in Prepros 6.1.1, **with SFTP only**.

This may be related to that question:  [Folders uploading in Prepros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791734/folders-uploading-in-prepros)

The **file** upload is OK, but Prepros will create **directories** in the wrong path!

### Example

I want to upload `new-directory/new-file` to `/home/myuser/www/`:

- If `new-directory` exists on the server ; no problem, the file is uploaded in there.
- If I upload a new file in a new directory ;

  1. Prepros will create the directory in `/home/myuser/home/myuser/www/new-directory`,
  2. then try to upload the file to `/home/myuser/www/new-directory` which doesn't exists…

Does anyone have found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

How is your FTP config?

Open FTP Settings and on Remote Path yout insert all the path to the directory you want. For example:

I want to upload a file to my test folder, then, on the remote path field, i will insert

**/public_html/test/**

This way all the files will be uploaded to this directory

Comment: My config is (SFTP) Remote Path: `/home/site/www`

But if I create a new file in a new directory, say `test/file.txt`, I got this error:

"An error occurred while uploading files. 
Error: Failed to upload 'User/…/test/file.txt' to `/home/site/www/test/file.txt`,
Error: No such file"

Because Prepros created the folder here: `/home/site/www/home/site/www/test`
Then tries to upload the file to: `/home/site/www/test/file.txt` but the directory isn't there!